Should I remove the ground plane under AC traces in my PCB?
Attached below are images of a 2-layer PCB layout I am currently designing. I have always had the habit of removing the ground plane underneath AC signals, but a more experienced PCB designer advised me that the removal of the ground plane should only be done near the connectors and high-power AC traces.
In this PCB, there are three isolated secondary windings from the same transformer providing the following voltages:

24VAC: Rectified using a full-bridge rectifier to power a DC motor that consumes approximately 90W.

14VAC: Used directly to power an AC lamp.

12VAC: Rectified and regulated to supply the digital circuits with 3.3V.


From an EMI perspective, would the return paths for the currents be negatively affected if I remove the ground plane under all AC traces and connectors across the board?
Alternatively, should I only cut the ground plane in the region where the AC connectors and traces are located? Or would it be better to leave a continuous ground plane underneath the entire system?



I would add a keepout around each of your mounting holes. Bigger than any standoffs or screwheads you are planning to use. There is no benefit for copper there.

You will benefit from swapping the relay cotact terminals by not needing vias under the relay.  This may improve reliablity.

you might want to move the 24VAC connectors to a more easily accessed location,  "Lamp conn" is in another hard reach corner, but not as bad.

Why would you remove the ground plane from under these traces? I see no useful reason to do that.

Given that this is low-frequency AC (50 or 60 Hertz), you can consider it to be DC for the purposes of impedance calculations on the PCB. The wavelength of these AC signals is much longer than the size of your entire PCB - about 5000 kilometers in fact. Removing the ground plane will have no effect on the propagation of these signals.
What it will have an influence on, though, is the path that return currents will take, as you already identified yourself. Given that this is a power application with large currents flowing through the ground plane, this is actually quite important both to prevent unwanted resistive voltage drops and for EMI reasons. An unbroken ground plane will provide a better (shorter and lower resistance) return path, so it's always a good idea to keep the ground plane intact underneath power traces.
In your case, you should fill the entire bottom layer of the board with ground plane wherever possible.
What you might want to do, though, is to increase the clearance between the ground plane and adjacent signals on the same layer in order to prevent accidental bridges during soldering. This can be done in the design rule settings of the CAD software you're using (KiCAD?). 0.5mm to 1mm is probably a good idea. Another thing to consider is to increase the default thickness of your signal traces - they look awfully thin and there doesn't seem to be any reason to keep them that way (lots of empty space around them). 0.5mm is likely a good starting point as well there.
You could also consider flooding the top layer with ground plane too and stitching it to the bottom plane with vias in a regular-ish grid to lower the plane resistance further.
And lastly, it looks like you've placed some (ground) vias within the pads of components. This will cause you trouble with manufacturing unless you very specifically know what you're doing there. Don't do it with this board, there's enough space to run a short trace to a via slightly away from the pad. It'll save you a lot of headaches during soldering (via-in-pad can suck solder away if not done properly).

What about clearance/creepage?

@Lundin OP mentioned that the board operates at 24V AC, which is absolutely not a problem for any standard two-layer board whether there's ground on the other side (or adjacent to the trace) or not.

Oh right, I just assumed it was 230 VAC mains.

Got it,  makes sense, especially about keeping the ground plane intact to ensure efficient current return and reduce resistance and EMI. I do have a specific question, though: for high-current traces, like 3 to 5A (24V AC, before rectification), is it still a good idea to keep the ground plane directly underneath them? Or would it be better to increase the distance a bit to avoid any potential interference or other issues?

I’m asking because I’ve noticed there’s often a recommendation to keep the ground plane slightly away from AC power signals even when the voltage is relatively low, like in this case with 24V AC.

@ever_pi the point of a ground plane with signals that actually do interfere with others (so, much higher frequency than yours) is to keep the electrical fields contained between traces and ground plane. Energy travels in the electrical field, not the conductors! So, especially to keep interference low, you'd want to keep ground below these traces. But as said before, at your frequencies, it doesn't matter.

For AC power traces, why would the return currents be on the ground, and not on the corresponding AC pair conductor?

@user1937198 A break in the ground plane doesn't just affect the signals it's directly underneath of, it affects every return current that needs to travel through the ground plane. So even if the AC traces themselves don't technically need the ground plane, the fact that the copper is removed still impedes everything else. Whether this actually matters depends on the layout in question. I've updated the answer to make that more clear.

The usual bridge rectifier + capacitor power supply draws pulsed current from the transformer, to charge the cap, on the peaks of the AC waveform.

These current pulses flows in traces between the transformer, rectifier, and smoothing cap. It will create a voltage drop due to Ohm's law.
On your PCB, the 12VAC bridge is connected to the 1000µF cap cap via a skinny trace, and this bit of trace is shared with current flowing from the cap into the rest of the circuit:

This will increase voltage ripple on your supply, and produce ripple with higher frequency content which regulators have more trouble rejecting. Best practice is to not share traces, and route from the bridge to the cap, then from the cap to the rest of the circuit, using separate traces.
Likewise, these current pulses will travel in the ground plane. It has very low impedance, so the resulting voltage drop should be pretty low. This would cause trouble if you have sensitive analog circuits on your board like a microphone preamp, it would cause some buzz.
Making holes in the ground plane means these current pulses will travel a longer path and create higher voltage drop along the way, adding more noise to your ground.
To avoid this you can flip the 24V rectifier bridge and rotate the 4700%F cap 90° so the bridge "-" output is close to the cap's "-" pin. For the 12VAC bridge, it's SMD you can simply route the "-" trace to the cap's "-" pin instead of using a via to the ground plane.
Using a ground plane has a bit of a "psychological effect" where we visually focus on traces and optimize them to make them shorter, while forgetting the result often is longer current paths through the ground plane. Basically you control how current flows in traces by routing, and you control how current flows in the ground plane by component placement.

Is "...make them shorted" a typo, which should be "...make them shorter"?

Nice catch! It was fat fingers ;)
